# Using multiprocessing to process DataFrame but column value not change

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing

I have a large dataframe and I want to remove the HTML tag in one of the columns. So I use BeautifulSoup and a for loop to do this work and it works fine. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

d = {'name': ['alan', 'bob', 'charle', 'dean'],
     'age':['23', '43', '56', '23'],
     'content': ['<p>test</p>', '<div>foo</div>', '<span>bar</span>',
                 '<div class='test'>test2</div>']}

data = pd.DataFrame(d)

for i in range(1, 10000):
    data.ix[i, 'content'] = BeautifulSoup(data.ix[i, 'content'], 
                                          'lxml').get_text()
```

Now I want to speed it up with multiprocessing，like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def work(n):
    data.ix[n, 'content'] = BeautifulSoup(data.ix[n, 'content'], 'lxml').get_text()

with Pool() as p:
    p.map(work, range(1, 1000))
```

The multiprocessing seems worked because my CPUs load go to 100%, but the column isn't changed.

Did I miss something? Or it just doesn't work in this way?

Comment: You code does not work like this. `data` is not defined.

Comment: sorry, I forget this. data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

Comment: Please add that to your code and make sure it runs now. We need to be able to replicate the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have edit my question, thank you.

Comment: With `multiprocessing` every process gets a forked or serialized copy of your namespaces. Changes will not be reflected back to the main process. Only the return value will be available later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes made inside the threads are not global, this means that any changes you make with `multiprocessing` will **not** change your data.

Instead, you can (and should) partition the work across the threads, and make the `work()` function return a new modified version of the data partition, and then combine (concatenate) the modified parts.

Taken originally from [here](http://blog.adeel.io/2016/11/06/parallelize-pandas-map-or-apply/), this code will do what you want:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import cpu_count,Pool

def work(data_part):
    data_part.content = data_part.content.map(lambda c: BeautifulSoup(c, 'lxml').get_text())
    return data_part

cores = cpu_count() #Number of CPU cores on your system
partitions = cores #Define as many partitions as you want

def parallelize(data, func):
    data_split = np.array_split(data, partitions)
    pool = Pool(cores)
    data = pd.concat(pool.map(func, data_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return data

data = parallelize(data,work)
```